# Error in oracle 11g sql

Tags: sql, oracle11g

I am trying to execute following queries but they are giving me errors-

```
select projectid, COALESCE(to_char(enddate,dd-mm-yy)-to_char(startdate,dd-mm-yy),startdate)  as duration
From projects;
```

Here I want to display the difference of enddate and startdate,and if Null then only the startdate.But this is giving me error.
This is the error-

```
ORA-00904: "YY": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 4 Column: 78
```

Also in another query I want to display just the year from the `startdate`.start date is in `dd-mm-yy`.How can I do it?

Comment: _'this is giving me error.'_ - why do so many people post a comment like this, then not bother to __post the actual error message__?

Comment: Post your error message (add it to your question)

Comment: The error is not caused by the shown code.

Comment: This is the error I am getting

Comment: @coder, the difference in dates is a number. Under what circumstances would the difference be NULL in your requirement?

Comment: The error you posted is because you need single quotes around `dd-mm-yy`.  When using `coalesce`, you have to have the same data types.  A time difference is not the same data type as a time stamp, so displaying a date in lieu of a time span won't work with coalesce...  Perhaps could convert to a string...

Comment: @LalitKumarB I have some enddate as `Null` in my database.So if enddate is `Null` diff will be `Null`.In that case,I want to display the `startdate`.

Comment: @sgeddes How can I do ths then because in oracle 11g we cant convert to string

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why are you converting the dates to strings, if you want the difference?  You want something like:

```
select projectid, (enddate - startdate) as diff
from projects;
```

I don't know what you mean by "if Null then only the startdate", but `coalesce()` can probably solve the problem.

EDIT:

If you want to show both the difference (a number) and a date, then you need to convert the values to strings:

```
select projectid,
       (case when end_date is null then to_char(end_date, 'YYYY-MM-DD')
             else to_char(end_date - start_date)
        end)
from projects;
```

Comment: Yes directly using enddate-startdate works,but I have some null values in the database.So when using `Collesce` like this-`collesce(enddate-startdate,startdate,enddate)`,it gives me error.

Comment: What do you want the value of the *difference* to be when one is NULL?  A typical approach is to use the current day's value.

Comment: If the end date is `Null` then the diff will also be `Null`.In that case I want to display just the startdate

Comment: `collesce(enddate-startdate,startdate,enddate)` gives me this error-`ORA-00932: inconsistent datatypes: expected NUMBER got DATE
00932. 00000 -  "inconsistent datatypes: expected %s got %s"`

Comment: It is also not working for me.I am getting this error using the edit above-
`ORA-00904: "PROJECT_ID": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
Error at Line: 1 Column: 8`

Comment: @Coder -- come on, really?  You should be able to figure that one out!